# Intallation XDS-x86 modula 2 compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, installation, pkgbuild

I am trying to install the compiler XDS-x86.
I' ve downloaded the package but when I type makepkg I get the error:
*ERROR: PKGBUILD does not exist*
Any hints?